# Git: resolving two working directories with unstaged work

Tags: git

I am working in two working directories but have gotten them out of sync because I'm dumb.

Both have unstaged changes since last being synced with main.

I altered "fileA" in `~/working` and "fileB" in `code/working`.

What are my best options?

- Turn `~/working` into a branch, merge it into main, then pull in `code/working`?
- Stash changes in `~/working`, push changes in `code/working`, pull into `~/working`, unstash, commit, push, then pull, ....
- Push `~/working` and try to force pull into `code/working` because the same file was not altered in each?
- Something else?

Comment: What is the actual problem? If one working directory was another person, that person would commit push and/or merge their change into `main` (or maybe even a feature branch). And you would merge/rebase `main` (or the feature branch) to get the change in your branch. You could do the exact same thing if the other person happens to be you as well. If the problem is that you wish for these changes to be in a single commit, then perhaps commit both separately, push one, cherry-pick it to your other one, and then squash it into your other commit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local directories as remote repos. Just run

```bash
git remote add otherlocal ../code/working
```

wherein `otherlocal` is the remote name (usually `origin`) and the last arg is your local directory.

After that, you can just do `git merge otherlocal/main`, `git pull otherlocal main`, `git push -u otherlocal branchname`, whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

> with unstaged work

Then you can simply add file modified in `workspace2` (and not staged yet: "unstaged work" from `workspace1`, using the [`git --work-tree` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt):

```bash
cd /path/to/workspace1
git --workstree=/path/to/workspace2 add -- a/file/toadd
git commit -m "Add file from workspace2"
```